# Fusion Chart Without Flash Player

Tags: asp.net, fusioncharts

I'm using Fusion Chart Version2.2 for asp.net. Web page runs fine when I install  flash player. Can I run the application without installing this flash player? I'm using FusionCharts.js

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="FusionCharts/FusionCharts.js"></script>
```

My code is here,

```
    //strXML will be used to store the entire XML document generated
    string strXML = null;
    //Generate the graph element
    strXML = @"<graph caption='" + strCaption + @"' subCaption='" + strSubCaption + @"' decimalPrecision='0' pieSliceDepth='30' formatNumberScale='0'
      xAxisName='" + xAxis + @"' yAxisName='" + yAxis + @"' rotateNames='1'>";

    int i = 0;
    foreach (DataRow dr2 in dt.Rows)
    {
        strXML += "<set name='" + dr2[0].ToString() + "' value='" + dr2[1].ToString() + "' color='" + color[i] + @"'  link=&quot;JavaScript:myJS('" + dr2["month"].ToString() + ", " + dr2["sales"].ToString() + "'); &quot;/>";
        i++;

    }

    //Finally, close <graph> element
    strXML += "</graph>";

    FCLiteral1.Text = FusionCharts.RenderChartHTML(
        "FusionCharts/FCF_Column3D.swf", // Path to chart's SWF
        "",                              // Leave blank when using Data String method
        strXML,                          // xmlStr contains the chart data
        "mygraph1",                      // Unique chart ID
        GraphWidth, GraphHeight,                   // Width & Height of chart
        false
        );
```

Can I use same version2.2 or need to upgrade the version?

Answer (score 2):

You are using flash based version which is deprecated. Try using FusionCharts upgraded version and ensure that the xml structure generated is according to the FusionCharts prescribed format.

Meanwhile you could check the detailed blog showcasing how to render charts supported by FusionCharts from database in VB.NET http://www.fusioncharts.com/blog/2017/02/rendering-fusioncharts-vb-net-using-database/

Comment: http://www.fusioncharts.com/download/free/ is this library helpful? Is it valid for life time?

Comment: Trial or evaluation version is free I guess but for production I guess you need to buy a license. you could check http://www.fusioncharts.com/buy/